# Getting Exponential Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

While converting float value to varchar its giving me exponential value.
For eg -

```
if '313185515' is float value then its varchar 
value I am getting is **3.13186e+008**
```

I don't want exponential value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using `STR`:

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(313185515, 10))
```

Or if you want decimals:

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(313185515, 10, 2))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8588

Good luck.

Comment: We can do this way too - CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Cast (ColumnName as Decimal(18,0)))

Answer (score 0):

We can do this way too -

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Cast (ColumnName as Decimal(18,0)))
```